# What's the smallest + cheapest keyboard that has a 1/4 inch jack output and runs on AAs?

Tags: audio, music

I got excited to see the Casio SA-76, which almost fit the description, but it doesn't have a 1/4 inch jack output.

I do not care about timbre or sound quality, because I want to run the keyboard through a vocoder while having access to the voices on my other "real" keyboard.

By smallest, I mean fewer than 49 keys. Smaller means lighter, and it's more aesthetic to have a tiny keyboard sitting on top of my other keyboard.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I don't mean a MIDI controller, but a keyboard that outputs its own tones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I occurs to me that my exact specification is satisfied by taking the Casio keyboard mentioned, which only has a headphone output, and use a 3.5mm male to 1/4 inch female adapter.